# sleep() over 1000 milis blocks Thread forever - android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth, sleep

I'm receiving real-time data from HC-05, just numbers from 0 to 1023.
SleepDuration variable is for the sleep duration between getting data from HC-05 and it can be chosen by the user between 1sec to 2 seconds, and this is the problem :

When the user chooses 1 second for SleepDuration, the program works fine but when he chooses over 1 second, this thread sleeps forever after getting few data.

This is my code for receiving data :

```
public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream

        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {

            // Read from the InputStream
            try {
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                incomingMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);

                try {
                    sleep(SleepDuration);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "write: Error reading Input Stream. " + e.getMessage());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does it block when there's no more data to read?

Comment: @FrancescoRe No, it blocks for no reason

Comment: Are you executing the code in the Main thread or in a separated thread?

Comment: a separated thread @FrancescoRe

Comment: Show me more code on how you start the thread

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you are blocked into the instruction **mmInStream.read(buffer)**

Basically when you call the read, you are blocking the client waiting for some data, if data does not come your code blocks in the read forever.

Comment: No, the data is coming, and it is working fine when I choose 1 second for sleep duration